# An application to learn English

Tags: educational, language, dictionary

I want an app to learn English by remembering vocabulary.

There's many recommandation which is required to be tried one by one.

It's best based on iso.

Comment: What operating system? (eg. Android? Windows? Linux? Several?) Must it be free? Otherwise what is your budget? Will you use the app for a month 8 hours per day, or for the rest of your life 1 hours per week? Depending on that, the solutions will be different. Please edit your question to include this information, then ask us to open, thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a "flash card" system. Of course, that is only reading, so you might not have perfect pronunciation. If you want something else, please make it clear in your question.

Comment: Try My Word List: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortylove.mywordlist.free

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/). Various collections of English words are available, such as [4000 Essential English Words](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/735471551).

Comment: Sounds good, but you could have described what it is/does. Even just saying "it's a flash card system" would have helped.